# Is there a way to use operator.itemgetter with slice notation?

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I have a bunch of numpy arrays in a python list `lst`. I can slice one of these arrays to get a specific view by indexing it with `[:, 1]`, for example.

I need to apply this slicing operation to all the numpy arrays in `lst`. Using generator comprehension, I could do:

```
(my_array[:, 1] for my_array in lst)
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to accomplish the same thing with `operator.itemgetter` and `map`.

`map(operator.itemgetter(:, 1), lst)` unsurprisingly results in a syntax error.

Comment: Why?  My impression is that `map` and `list comprehension` have about the same speed.  I find comprehensions to be more readable.

Comment: @hpaulj Reason I like to use `map` / `filter` over comprehensions is to 1) avoid having to name a local variable and 2) for brevity (especially when I have methods like `itemgetter` and `attrgetter` imported into local namespace).

Comment: `itemgetter` is a class with readable python code. As documented it is mainly designed as a way to do "advanced indexing" on lists, indexing a list with a list (array already allows that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slice syntax generates `slice` objects for you. You'll have to create them explicitly to pass to `itemgetter`. Since `itemgetter(x,y)(a)` is equivalent to `(a[x], a[y])`, you also need to use parentheses to ensure that you pass a single `tuple` consisting of your `slice` and the `int` index.

```
# [:] -> slice(None)
map(operator.itemgetter((slice(None), 1)), lst)
```

---

A useful tool for figuring out what exactly slicing syntax does is to define a small class

```
class A:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print(key)
```

Then you can do quick checks like

```
>>> A()[:,1]
(slice(None, None, None), 1)
```

(`slice(None)` is short for `slice(None, None, None)`.)