# Parameterized access of row or column of pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to get slices of a `pandas.DataFrame` using an `axis` argument to specify either rows or columns.  That is, I would like the functionality provided by the function `_loc_axis` in the MWE below.  Is there an easy way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

def _loc_axis(df, idx, axis):
    """Call loc along proper axis"""
    # Axis as integer, error if axis is invalid
    axis = {0: 0, 'index': 0,
            1: 1, 'columns': 1}[axis]
    return (df.loc[idx, :] if axis==0 else
            df.loc[:, idx])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]],
    index=['a','b','c'],
    columns=['D','E','F'],
)

print(df)
print(_loc_axis(df, ['a','b'], axis='index'))
print(_loc_axis(df, ['F','D'], axis='columns'))
```

Produces output:

```
   D  E  F
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6
c  7  8  9

   D  E  F
a  1  2  3
b  4  5  6

   F  D
a  3  1
b  6  4
c  9  7
```

Comment: Hi, are you asking if there is a way to simplify even more your function?

Comment: I am trying to tell if there is a standard pandas function that does this.

Comment: *Is there a standard pandas function that does this?* I fear not, sorry.

Comment: You can use `operator.itemgetter` in combination with `slice` objects on `df.loc`, see [Is there a way to use operator.itemgetter with slice notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61762748/is-there-a-way-to-use-operator-itemgetter-with-slice-notation). E.g., `itemgetter((slice(1), "A"))(df.loc)` is equal to `df.loc[:1, "A"]`. Crucially, you can pass `None` to `slice` which is equal to `[:]`.